# How to find bad references in a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I have a data problem I need to clean up. Basically I have two tables storing "package" information, one table for documents and one table for audit information. I have entries in the package tables that reference documents that no longer exist and have been replaced (same name but different id) and I want to write a query to find all the bad ones and which new document should replace them. The only thing linking these two is a string value in the audit table which stores the document name (not id).

I've setup a sample schema here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/997bda/1

- package_s is the single values for a package in our application
- package_r is the repeating values for a package in our application

  - (these are joined with the same value in the id column)
- audit_info is all the audit information in a package
- docs is all the documents that can be attached to a package

This query finds the packages with bad attachments (may be more than one per package)

```
select distinct ps.pkgname, pr.doc_list
from package_s ps, package_r pr
where ps.id = pr.id
and not exists (
  select 1 from docs
  where pr.doc_list = id
  )
order by 1,2 asc
;
```

I need to build a query with the following rules:

- I need to return at least the package id, the position value and the new document id (I will build an update statement to put this new document id in the row matching the package id / position in the package_r table)
- the way to get the document name from the audit information is:
  SUBSTR(description,0,INSTR(description,'[')-2)
- If the document was Added and then Removed, it should be ignored (string_1)
- string_2 must not be 'Supporting'
- the new document must match
  state = 'Master'
  latest = 1
  pub = '0'

Right now I have a semi-working script that works on a per package basis, but the problem is affecting 2000+ packages. I find the audit entries that don't match documents correctly attached to the package and then search for those names in the document table. The problem with this is since there is no direct link between the package and document tables, if there are multiple problem attachments on one package, each "new" document is returned once per position value, i.e.

```
package id      bad doc id      position      new doc id
p1              d1              -1            d1-new
p1              d1              -1            d4-new
p1              d4              -2            d1-new
p1              d4              -2            d4-new
```

It doesn't matter which new id goes into which position value, but the duplication result problem like this makes it hard to mass generate update scripts, some manual filtering would be required.

This is a somewhat complex and unique data issue, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This query works according to informations provided:

```
with ai as (
  select a1.audited_id id, dc.id doc_id, dc.docname,
      row_number() over (partition by a1.audited_id order by dc.id) rn
    from audit_info a1
    join docs dc
      on dc.state = 'Master' and dc.latest = 1 and dc.pub = '0'
        and dc.docname = substr(a1.description, 1, instr(a1.description, '[')-2)
    where string_1 = 'Added' and string_2 <> 'Supporting'
      and not exists (
        select * from audit_info a2
          where a2.audited_id = a1.audited_id and string_1 = 'Removed'
            and a2.description = a1.description )
      and not exists (  -- here matching docs are eliminated
        select 1 from package_r pr 
          where pr.id = a1.audited_id and pr.doc_list = dc.id ) ),
p as (
  select ps.id, ps.pkgname, pr.doc_list, pr.position,
      row_number() over (partition by ps.id order by doc_list) rn
    from package_s ps
      join package_r pr on pr.id = ps.id
    where not exists ( select * from docs where pr.doc_list = docs.id ) 
  )
select p.id, p.pkgname, p.doc_list, p.position
    , ai.docname, ai.doc_id
  from p join ai on ai.id = p.id and p.rn = ai.rn
  order by p.id, p.doc_list, ai.doc_id
```

Output:

```
ID  PKGNAME  DOC_LIST  POSITION  DOCNAME  DOC_ID
--  -------  --------  --------  -------  ------
p1  000001   d3              -3  doc3     d3-new
p1  000001   d4              -4  doc4     d4-new
p2  000002   d5              -2  doc5     d5-new
p4  000004   d6              -1  doc6     d6-new
```

---

Edit: Answers to issues reported in comments

> it is identifying packages that do not have bad values, and then the doc_list column is blank,

Note that query (my subquery `p`) for identyfing packages is basically your query, I just added counter there.
I guess that some process/application or someone manually cleared column `doc_list` in `package_r`. 
If you don't want such entries, just add condition `and trim(doc_list) is not null` in subquery `p`.

> for the ones it gets right on the package part (they have a bad value) it is bringing back the wrong docname/doc_id to replace the bad value with, it is a different doc_id in the list.

I understand this only partially. Can you add such entries to your examples (in Fiddle or just edit your question and add problematic input rows and expected output for them?)

*"It doesn't matter which new id goes into which position value"*.
Assignment I made this way - if we had two old docs with names "ABC", "DEF" and corrected docs have names "XXA", "DE12"
then they will be linked as "ABC"->"DE12" and "DEF"->"XXA" (alphabetical ordering seems more rational than totally random).
To make assigning random change `order by ...` to `order by null` in both row_number() functions.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the work you've put into this! In the sqlfiddle data it does seem to work. I've tested this on our test database and it has some issues: it is identifying packages that do not have bad values, and then the doc_list column is blank, and for the ones it gets right on the package part (they have a bad value) it is bringing back the wrong docname/doc_id to replace the bad value with, it is a different doc_id in the list. I'm trying to ensure there are no other data issues that might be causing this

Comment: I removed first part of answer as it had only "historical" meaning and added part addressing your comments.